# How to calculate the log marginal distribution in Tweedie's formula?

Tags: bayesian, poisson-regression, empirical-bayes

[2018  Bayes, oracle Bayes, and empirical Bayes](https://efron.ckirby.su.domains/papers/2018BayesOBayesEBayes.pdf)

[2021  Empirical Bayes: Concepts and methods](https://efron.ckirby.su.domains/papers/2021EB-concepts-methods.pdf)

[Two modeling strategies for empirical Bayes estimation](https://efron.ckirby.su.domains/papers/2014EBModelingRevised.pdf)

[2013  Empirical Bayes modeling, computation, and accuracy](https://efron.ckirby.su.domains/papers/2013EBModeling.pdf)

I have tried to read these papers (which is difficult for me). But I still haven't understood how to specifically calculate the log marginal distribution in Tweedie's formula, especially implementing it in code, so if anyone can give me any possible help, I'd be very grateful.

My current understanding is to use Poisson regression to get the smooth log marginal distribution, and then compute the first order derivative of the Poisson regression estimate (it seems that the paper's approach is to use numerical differentiation), and that this first order derivative is the Bayesian correction in Tweedie's formula, and I'm not sure if I'm understanding this correctly.
Assuming it is correct, how should the model for Poisson regression be chosen?